# ¿Cómo sustituir este js por jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente html y js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

<html lang="es">
    <iframe src="https://webdenoticias.com/" id="iframe" onload="cargar_noticias()" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</html>
```

```
var iframe = '';

window.onload=function(){
    iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
}

function cargar_noticias(){
    var noticias = iframe .getElementsByClassName("titulo_portada");
    console.log(noticias);
} 

console.log(noticias);
```

Como veis la intención es coger todos los class del iframe cuyo nombre sea "titulo_portada", pero con jquery.

He probado con .find, pero nada.

¿Cómo se haría? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias cosas por observar en tu código, lo primero es que **noticias no está definido**, ya que el alcance de la variable es solo válido para la función, por lo que en la línea final (`console.log`), debería dar un `ReferenceError`.

Otra cosa, es que `iframe` seguirá vacío, pues estás esperando a que cargue la página para asignarlo, cuando deberías esperar a que cargue la página para asignarlo y llamar a la función o esperar a que cargue la página para ejecutar la función dentro del `eventListener`

Arreglando todo esto, es muy sencillo, ya que usas un ID para el `<iframe>`, podrías usar el selector de ID (`#ejemplo`) y luego el selector de hijos (`>`), quedando el selector así `#iframe > .titulo_portada`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://webdenoticias.com/" id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $("#iframe > .titulo_portada").each((i, el) => {
        console.log(el);
    });
    // Usar el método each para recorrer todos los elementos con el selector
    // Devuelve un array, que se recorre con each: "i" es el índice y "el" es el elemento
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora entiendo mejor el código.

El problema es que me sigue sin coger dichos elementos en el console y ya no entiendo si es por la web del iframe en específico.

En vez de "https://webdenoticias.com/" sería "https://vandal.elespanol.com" por si quieres probar y ver si a ti te coge algo.